# Как с помощью fread осуществить считывание информации в список

Tags: c

Застрял с функцией fread.
Есть очередь, реализованная через список:

```
struct Bus_Info {
   char b_n[9];
   char name[15];
   char way[4];
   int parking;
   int lesion;
};

struct List {
    struct Bus_Info bus_info;
    int size;
    struct List * next;
};
```

Нужно реализовать считывание данных с файла и добавление их в очередь.
Я так понимаю:

```
int main()
{
    struct List * first;//указатель на начало очереди
    struct List * last;//указатель на конец очереди
    first = NULL;
    last = first;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Bus_Info.dat","r");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Its impossible to open");
        return 1;
    }

    И в этом месте нужно описать fread() так что бы он считывал данные в структуру, и добавлять элемент в список пока не дойдем до конца файла.
    Как это возможно осуществить?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно открыть файл в бинарном режиме и считывать по одной структуре

```
 size_t size;
 struct Bus_Info * buf = malloc(sizeof(struct Bus_Info));
 fp = fopen("Bus_Info.dat","rb");

 size = fread(buf,sizeof(struct Bus_Info),1,fp);
```

Если структура статична и чтение/запись происходит программно Я бы сделал так.

```
struct Bus_Info 
{
  char b_n[9];
  char name[15];
  char way[4];
  int parking;
  int lesion;
}__attribute__((packed));

 struct Bus_Info * begin_list;
 struct Bus_Info * current;
 int amount = 0;

 int main(int argc,char * argv[])
 {
   int rc;
   FILE *fp;
   struct stat st;
   stat("Bus_Info.dat",&st);
   amount= st.size;
   if(amount == 0){
     return 1;
   }
   if(!(amount % (sizeof(struct Bus_Info)))){
     /*ошибка файла*/
     return 1;
   }
   begin_list = malloc(amount);

   fp = fopen("Bus_Info.dat","rb");
   if (fp==NULL){
     printf("Its impossible to open");
     return 1;
   }
   rc = fread(begin_list,amount,1,fp);
   if(rc != amount){
     /*ошибка чтения*/
     return 1;
   }
   /*получаем колличество элементов и указатель на первый элемент*/
   amount /= sizeof(struct(Bus_Info));
   current = begin_list;

   /*смешение на любую структуры*/
   current += number;
   /*доступ к элементам */ 
   current->b_n;
   current->name;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Не получится, так как те поля, которые в структуре являются массивами, не обязаны иметь полную длину.

Comment: @Zealint длина поля небольшая можно при записи в файл занулять. И при чтении там будут нули. Для небольшой строки не критично.

Comment: __attribute__((packed)); не совсем понятно, что это такое?

Comment: __attribute__((packed)) этот атрибут говорит компилятору не выравнивать структуры. Тоесть в 32 разрядной системе структуры будет занимать 36 байт. А без этого атрибута в 32 разрядной системе структура будет выровнена по 4 байта и займет 40 байт .